# Preprocessing for the final model to be deployed

Tags: machine-learning, python, preprocessing, overfitting, data-leakage

Typically for a ML workflow, we import the data (`X` and `y`), split the `X` and `y` into `train`, `valid` and `test`, preprocess the data for `train`, `valid` and `test`(scale, encode, impute nan values etc), perform HP tuning and after getting the best model with the best HP, we fit the final model to the whole dataset (i.e. `X` and `y`).

Now the issue here is that `X` and `y` are not preprocessed as only the `train`, `valid` and `test` are preprocessed. So when fitting the final model on `X` and `y`, we'll be getting an error as we haven't encoded (and performed other preprocessing steps) `X` and `y`. How are we then supposed to train the final model on the whole dataset? Do we preprocess `X` and `y` before fitting the final model? And if so won't it lead to **data leakage/ overfitting?**

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new experiment *the full data is the training set*. There's no test set or validation set.

> How are we then supposed to train the final model on the whole dataset? Do we preprocess X and y before fitting the final model?

Yes, and it's important to apply the exact same preprocessing method as was done on the original training set, now using the full data as training set. Any difference would invalidate the performance measured in the first experiment.

> And if so won't it lead to data leakage/ overfitting?

The preprocessing steps are determined on the training set only, then the exact same steps can be applied to the test set (or validation set).

In this case there's no test set anymore, so there cannot be data leakage. Of course the original test set cannot be used anymore as a test set, since it's now part of the training set.

There might be some overfitting, but it's not related to using the full dataset. Of course the first experiment should be used to check for overfitting before using the full data as training set. Once the model is trained on the full data, there's no way to check for overfitting anymore (unless there's some additional unseen labelled data that can be used as test set).

Comment: ` Of course the first experiment should be used to check for overfitting before using the full data as training set.` How can I do that?

Comment: The standard way is to obtain the performance on both the training set and the test set (or validation set), if the training performance is very high and test set is much lower then there is overfitting.